# Using Hibernate 4.0.1 in JBoss 6.0

Tags: jboss6.x, hibernate-4.x

I have to use version 4.0.1 of Hibernate in my enterprise application. The EAR is deployed into a JBoss 6.0 Container.

The ear file contains the following hibernate jars:

```
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-search-analyzers-4.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-search-engine-4.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-search-engine-4.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
```

According to [Upgrade Hibernate version in JBOSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277447/upgrade-hibernate-version-in-jboss) I've tried to configure custom classloading using the follwing jboss-app.xml and jboss-classloading.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application 1.4//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-app>
  <loader-repository>
    com.acme.sample:archive=Sample
    <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config> 
  </loader-repository>
</jboss-app>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
  domain="sample.ear"
  export-all="NON_EMPTY"
  import-all="true"
  parent-first="false">
</classloading>
```

When starting up the JBoss 6 Container following lines occur in the log file:

```
09:49:55,238 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
09:49:55,265 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
```

Seems as if Hibernate 4.0.1 has been detected. But then the following exception occurs:

```
09:49:55,388 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=sample-SNAPSHOT.ear/lib/persistence_impl-0.0.21-SNAPSHOT.jar#sample state=Create: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.as.jpa.scanner.HackTLScanner cannot be cast to org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.Scanner
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildScanner(Ejb3Configuration.java:415) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:582) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.jboss.jpa.builder.DefaultCEMFBuilder.build(DefaultCEMFBuilder.java:47) [:1.0.2-alpha-3]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.scanner.HackCEMFBuilder.build(HackCEMFBuilder.java:49) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:275) [:1.0.2-alpha-3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_26]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
```

In the exception stack trace the version 3.6.0.Final of hibernate is mentioned. Seems as if the Container still tries to create the JPA Persistence Unit using the version of hibernate that ships with JBoss.

Can anybody give me a hint on what I am doing wrong and how to configure the custom classloading so that JBoss uses the Hibernate version that is packaged in the EAR file.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this? I'm seeing the same issue here, and any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Petter, we have not found any solution to this until now

Answer (score 0):

I have done a workaround for this problem and it works...

my ear structure is like this--->

```
accountEAR.ear
|
|--lib
    |<all jars for hibernate 4.0.1 and mysql jdbc jar>
|
|--META-INF
    | application.xml
    | jboss-app.xml
    | jboss-classloading.xml
    | mysql-ds.xml
|
|-- account_persistence.jar
```

jboss version is 6.1 and mysql version 5.1

jboss-app.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Java EE Application 5.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd" >
<jboss-app>
    <loader-repository>
        com.accountEAR:loader=accountEAR
        <loader-repository-config>
            java2ParentDelegation=false
        </loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</jboss-app>
```

jboss-classloading.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classloading 
    xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY"
    import-all="true"
    parent-first="false"/>
```